# Motivation behind definition of product measure.

Tags: measure-theory, intuition, motivation, product-measure

Consider two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal G,\nu)$.In standard measure theory books they define product measure as follows:

$(\mu\times \nu)(E)=\int_X\nu(E_x)d\mu =\int_Y \mu(E^y)d\nu$.

I am trying to find the motivation behind this definition.One may be that $E_x$ is the length of the small strip cut out from the set by $x$ and $d\mu(x)$ denotes a small differential length which partitions the set $X$.So,multiplying them and then integrating which is basically adding we get the area within that set intuitively.The assumption $\sigma$-finite is needed to ensure that area calculated by taking vertical partitions is the same as taking horizontal partitions of $E$.Is my intuition correct?

[image]

Comment: I have usually seen it defined on rectangles and then constructed with an outer measure approach.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you suggest me a book where I can find this approach.

Comment: My apologies, I misremembered. The only construction I can find using outer measure came from class notes of Paul Chernoff. The closest I could find was from Kolmogorov & Fomin, but they use inner & outer measure which I think is a little clumsier and more work than necessary. Rudin is as in your question, and Durrett uses a semiring approach.

Comment: I have not read it through, but this seems to use the outer measure approach: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/245a-notes-6-outer-measures-pre-measures-and-product-measures/.

Comment: Two important uses are constructing independent random variables, and using Fubinis theorem to compute integrals. The fact that the measure is uniquely specified by its values on product sets makes the exact definition not very important. The $\sigma$-finite assumption is needed to prove that your definition is even well defined, aka Tonellis theorem.